# How do I route common named controllers by subdomain in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-routing

I am trying to figure out how to successfully use the same controller name in the URL, but route different controllers.  Dependant on the existence of a subdomain.

Example.

http://www.mysite.com/pages/1
Routes to the SitePages Controller

http://anyothersubdomain.mysite.com/pages/1
Routes to the UserPages Controller

Up until now, I have been doing this on the controller level.  But it seems like too much logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [Request Routing](http://agilewebdevelopment.com/plugins/request_routing) and [Subdomain Routes](http://agilewebdevelopment.com/plugins/subdomain_routes) plugins.  One of those should do the trick for you.